# Чтение одного символа из консоли

Tags: c#

Пользователю надо ввести один символ, и что бы он поместился в переменную типа string.Если я использую `Console.ReadKey` или `Console.Read` то выдает ошибку. Мне нужно что бы пользователь ввел один символ на клавиатуре (не число), и сразу программа пошла дальше. Однако это можно сделать через `Console.ReadLine`, однако тут пользователь должен будет нажимать энтер после ввода. Да и ввести может не один(да, его можно потом обрезать, но всеже). Видел программы, в которых это делалось, но уже не помню, а найти не могу. Подскажите реализацию.

Comment: Точнее опишите вашу задачу. Вам точно `string` нужен? Или нужно узнать какая клавиша была нажата? `Console.ReadKey()` возвращает не `string`, а структуру `ConsoleKeyInfo`, в которой есть свойства `Key` (оно подойдет, если вам нужно узнать что за клавиша была нажата) и `KeyChar` (оно подойдет, если вам нужен именно символ)

Comment: @Андрей допустим, мне нужно знать, какая из клавиш wasd была нажата, а в зависимости от этого исполнять другую часть программы.

Comment: В таком случае вам нужно именно `Key`, оно выдаст одно и то же значение независимо от того: нажаты ли `Shift`, `Ctrl`, `Alt`; включена ли английская раскладка клавиатуры; включен ли `CapsLock`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
var x = Console.ReadKey();
Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine("Вы нажали на - \"{0}\"", x.KeyChar);
Console.ReadLine();
```